# StandardInput not working for sending commands to CLI application C#

Tags: c#, io-redirection

I'm having trouble with sending data to CLI application using Process.StandardInput. In short, it doesn't work, but it should, at least as I know. I've searched everywhere and everything is the same as my code. One thing different, my application is Windows Forms and process starting code is in referenced DLL because I decided to separate GUI code and other code in separate projects.

Here how I'm creating and starting process:

```cs
Process serverProcess = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(ServerInstance.ServerExecutable, LaunchArguments);
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = ServerInstance.RootDirectory;
serverProcess.StartInfo = startInfo;
serverProcess.ErrorDataReceived += ServerProcess_ErrorDataReceived;
serverProcess.OutputDataReceived += ServerProcess_OutputDataReceived;
serverProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
serverProcess.Exited += ServerProcess_Exited;
serverProcess.Start();
serverProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
serverProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
serverProcess.WaitForExit();
```

When process outputs in console (redirected), it successfully fires `OutputDataReceived` event, but when I trying to use `serverProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("command")` it just ignores it, nothing happens.

So I need help with that, do I need to move all code into GUI project, or even into Form (which is bad for me), or I could make it work, I've seen other projects launching same process and sending CLI commands to the same process (actually same application), but for some reason, mine is not working.

Thank you!

EDIT:

Here some of the code from application I trying to run and send data:

```
// ...
    public static void startDedInput() => new Thread(new ThreadStart(Main.startDedInputCallBack))
    {
      IsBackground = true,
      Name = "Server Input Thread"
    }.Start();
 
    public static void startDedInputCallBack()
    {
      while (!Netplay.Disconnect)
      {
        Console.Write(": ");
        string str1 = Console.ReadLine();
        string str2 = str1;
        string lower1 = str1.ToLower();
        try
        {
          if (lower1 == Language.GetTextValue("CLI.Help_Command"))
          {
            Console.WriteLine(Language.GetTextValue("CLI.AvailableCommands"));
            Console.WriteLine("");
            List<string> stringList = new List<string>()
            {
// ...
```

EDIT:

So I've written simple CLI program using my code, and it doesn't work either, there is literally whole code of it:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string pathToInst = Console.ReadLine();
        ServerInstance instance = ServerInstance.LoadServerInstanceFromFile(pathToInst);

        ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager(instance);
        serverManager.ErrorDataReceived += ServerManager_ErrorDataReceived;
        serverManager.OutputDataReceived += ServerManager_OutputDataReceived;
        Console.WriteLine("Starting server...");
        serverManager.Run();
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("> ");
            string command = Console.ReadLine();
            serverManager.InvokeCommand(command);
        }
    }

    private static void ServerManager_OutputDataReceived(object? sender, ServerConsoleDataReceivedEventArgs e
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.DataString);
    }

    private static void ServerManager_ErrorDataReceived(object? sender, ServerConsoleDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine(e.DataString);
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
}
```

And it behaves exactly like WinForms app, it reads output, but doesn't sending data to StandardInput

In this [project](https://github.com/oiisamiio/TerrariaDedicatedServerGui/blob/30f5c04e2bb6f065fffa447f25a8061813120757/cls/ServerClass/Controller.cs) that I found, it seems that it written exactly the same, but it works, I've tried it.

Why so? Only difference it seems that my code for process running is implemented in separate class library project

Comment: Is the ServerExecutable also a application you wrote? If yes is it Windows Forms? Are you sure it is ready for input when you send data.

Comment: No, It's not mine application, I just know, that it is a game, written in XNA and confirmed it using dotPeek. I will add a snipped of code how input is handled in CLI app

Comment: Does it work when you launch the target program from the command line and manually send input?  Is there output you need to consume before the input prompt appears?

Comment: Yes, I can run it with "cmd" and just double clicking EXE, I can type commands and it responds to them

Comment: GUI apps don't use StandardInput for input, it is only usable for console mode apps.

Comment: Destination app that I wanna send commands using StandardInput is CLI, not a GUI. I've seen other GUI app that sends data to the same (same executable on my system) destination CLI app the same way as I am, but I must doing something wrong, since mine doesn't work. However mine applicaiton is actually Windows Forms

Answer (score 1):

As I had the same problem I looked into the project you linked.
The one difference is that they are writing to the stream as Unicode.

Testing this a bit I got the Terraria server to run with `process.StartInfo.StandardInputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;`. This seem to be dependent on the process receiving the input as for example a Windows `cmd` will not work with this setting.